# How to determine if a website has been hijacked?

Tags: web-browser, websites, url-redirection, web, url

I noticed that the URL of a website I sometimes visit was redirecting to a new URL.  I noticed this through a tool that I use that does not actually load the new URL.

I was surprised by this change, and I wondered if the site had been hijacked.  But, besides checking `whois` information for the new domain (which can be forged), I wasn't really sure how to tell if the change was legitimate.

In this particular case, the site was `archive.is`, and it was redirecting to `archive.vn`.

Is there a way to determine if a website has been hijacked without actually loading the URL in a web browser?